# How can i test none .java sources generated by annotation processor?

Tags: java, unit-testing, code-generation, annotation-processing, annotation-processor

I have been doing some annotation processing using Java APT, and i was able to generate .java files out of annotated classes following TDD practice, every thing went so far so good as long as i am generating .java files, for testing i used [google-compile-testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing) and here is how i have been doing the testing for the generated sources :

```
@Test
public void testGeneratedSource() throws Exception {
    Truth.assert_().about(javaSource()).that(JavaFileObjects.forResource("source class .java goes here"))
            .processedWith(new UiFormProcessor()).compilesWithoutError()
            .and()
            .generatesSources(JavaFileObjects.forSourceString("","expected generated class content goes here"));

}
```

with this i was able to check and validates the generated .java files.

but then i wanted to generate some .html files and i wanted to be able to test my generated html content.

but using the above method fails as it is expecting .java files and it throws the following Assertion error

```
java.lang.AssertionError: Did not find a generated file corresponding to .java

at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:27)
at com.google.common.truth.FailureStrategy.fail(FailureStrategy.java:23)
at com.google.testing.compile.JavaSourcesSubject$SuccessfulCompilationBuilder.generatesFiles(JavaSourcesSubject.java:491)
at com.progressoft.annotation.processor.UiFormsTest.emptyAnnotatedClass_shouldGenerateEmptyHtmlFormTemplate(UiFormsTest.java:39)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:117)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:262)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:84)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

the error indicates that i should be generating .java files, but i know with APT you can generate any kind of source code, but i think the issue here is in the calls or the parameters i do for testing, i have been trying to figure how to use the [google-compile-testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing) to test none java generated source, but with no luck.

Does anybody know how to test .html or any other content other java source with [google-compile-testing](https://github.com/google/compile-testing)?

Comment: i found the answer for this question but i cant post it as i am banned from answering, i will post the answer once i can.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it can help to use another JavaFileObjects method: **.forResource(URL)**

I think this could work:
(the paths are examples)

```
URL urlPersonJava = getResourceURL("src/test/java/", 
                              "com/github/funthomas424242/domain/Person.java");
URL urlPersonBuilderHtml = getResourceURL("src/test/expectations/", 
                              "PersonBuilder.html");

assertAbout(javaSource())
        .that(JavaFileObjects.forResource(urlPersonJava))
        .processedWith(processor1)
        .compilesWithoutError()
        .and()               
        .generatesSources(JavaFileObjects.forResource(urlPersonBuilderHtml));
```

Comment: what is getResourceURL here?

Comment: see: https://github.com/Huluvu424242/rades-annotations/blob/dc404acf3847d14431112ffa3fb3dc8465670cd6/src/test/java/com/github/funthomas424242/rades/annotations/accessors/processors/RadesAccessorProcessorTest.java
protected static URL getResourceURL(String projectSrcRoot, String resourcePath) throws MalformedURLException {
        final Path tmpPath = Paths.get(projectSrcRoot + resourcePath);
        final URL resourceURL = tmpPath.toAbsolutePath().toUri().toURL();
        return resourceURL;
    }

Comment: Additionally there is an method .withStringContents
https://javadoc.io/static/com.google.testing.compile/compile-testing/0.19/com/google/testing/compile/CompileTester.SuccessfulFileClause.html#withStringContents-java.nio.charset.Charset-java.lang.String-